# Access Powershell Output from $admins=Get-LocalGroupMember -Group "administrators"` in Django app

Tags: django, powershell

I´m trying to access the `Powershell` Output from `$admins=Get-LocalGroupMember -Group "administrators"` in my Django app.

**views.py**

```
def psAPI(request): 
    if request.method == 'POST':
        admins=request.POST['admins']
        print(admins)
        return HttpResponse(status=200)
```

**Ps Script**

```
$admins=Get-LocalGroupMember -Group "administrators"
$Body =@{
    "admins"=$admins
}
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri <url>/psAPI/ -Method Post -Body $Body
```

**wanted Ouptut in Python**

```
ObjectClass Name                          PrincipalSource 
----------- ----                          --------------- 
User    DESKTOP-*******\Administrator      Local
```

**the Output I got**
`System.Object[]`

Comment: Change `$admins=Get-LocalGroupMember -Group "administrators"` to `$admins=Get-LocalGroupMember -Group "administrators" |Format-Table |Out-String`